# Discontinuous first integral of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f_j: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad j=1,...,n$ be $C^1$ or even smooth functions. We define the following system of autonomous ODEs:
$$\dot{x}=f_j(x_1,...,x_n), \quad j=1,...,n$$
A first integral (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/First_integral) is a differentiable map
$$I: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad  I(x_1(t),...,x_n(t))=c(x_1(0),...,x_n(0))$$
which is constant on every trajectory. I.e. $c: U/[\sim] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where two points are identified under $\sim$ if they are connected by a solution.

**My question is the following:** Why are first integrals always defined as differentiable functions? Can there also be discontinuous first integrals? By that, I mean $I(x_1(t),...,x_n(t))$ is still constant on a solution but that the value of the constant is discontinuous in the inital condition. I.e. $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}I(x_1(t)+\varepsilon,...,x_n(t)+\varepsilon)-(x_1(t),...,x_n(t)) \neq 0$?

To mee it seems that this is forbidden by the way differntiable ODEs work. But I am unable to find a proof.

**Edit:** The first integrals should be written as polynomials with variable coefficients in the trajectories. I.e.
$$I=\sum_{i_1,...,i_n}^d b_{i_1,...,i_n}(x_1,...,x_n)x_1(t)^{i_1}\cdot ... \cdot x_n(t)^{i_n}$$ where $b_{i_1,...,i_n}(x_1,...,x_n)$ could be discontinuous functions. If such first integrals can exists

Comment: Any discontinuous function $I\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is constant on the integral curves of the trivial ODE $y' = 0$.
So the answer is yes, they do exist.
The real question would be "are these functions interesting?" and for that, I think the answer would be "no".